# Angular4 - cant implement password match validator

Tags: angular

From Angular docs:

```
const form = new FormGroup({
  password: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(2)),
  passwordConfirm: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(2)),
}, passwordMatchValidator);


function passwordMatchValidator(g: FormGroup) {
   return g.get('password').value === g.get('passwordConfirm').value
      ? null : {'mismatch': true};
}
```

I don't know how to call that `passwordMatchValidator` function. Tried something like:

`<div *ngIf="form.passwordMatchValidator">`

But without any success...

Comment: You don't need to call it. It is called everytime changes happens in form. Or what do you mean with **calling** it?

Comment: @AJT_82 but how do i show the error for this validation? I want to show the div element with some text that says "passwords do not match"

Comment: `<div *ngIf="form.hasError('mismatch')">` :)

Comment: @AJT_82 - Jeez... Thanks! If you provide the answer i could accept it, otherwise will delete it soon

Comment: Done! Glad to hear it was such a quick fix! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the div with the error message if passwords don't match, you just do:

```
<div *ngIf="form.hasError('mismatch')">
```